Upgrading from mysql 5 to mysql 8 gets me Incorrect string value
I am upgrading a system from mysql5 to mysql8 and got an error and I don't know how to fix it. I hope you can advise me.
I created my tables from scratch with default settings for collation with all the text/varchar fields in the tables are utf8mb4_general_ci. The table and the database are also utf8mb4_general_ci
I have this code:
   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO loginlog (usr, pwd, ip, tme) VALUES ('" .
      $login1 . "','" .
      $password1 . "','" .
      MyRealIpAddr() . "','" .
      date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "')";
   $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die($sql1 . " " .mysqli_error($conn));

My test values are then coded to $sql1 as follows:
INSERT INTO loginlog (usr, pwd, ip, tme) VALUES ('[DelaRosa.Cárdenas-Pedro]','[1234]','210.217.200.143','2024-08-06 14:16:49')
and I get this error: Incorrect string value: '\xE1rdena...' for column 'usr' at row 1 
If I take the $sql1 in phpMyAdmin (sql tab for this table) and run the query, the insert is succesful.
If I use the very same script now with any user that doesn't contain any accented chars,the insert is succesful in the script and phpMydmin, like
INSERT INTO loginlog (usr, pwd, ip, tme) VALUES ('[Campo.Adem-Juan]','[1234]','210.217.200.143','2024-08-06 14:40:19')
My script is ANSI coded and if I change it to UTF-8 without BOM the same error shows.
Any idea is aprecciated.

Don't use string concatenation to create queries, use a prepared statement with parameters. I don't know if this will solve the problem, but it might.

you also shouldn't store plaintext passwords in the database, you should use password hashing.

it seems your input is not utf

You should especially not be putting passwords into logs, hashed or not.

and yeah, \xE1 would be invalid UTF8 at that position, and also maps to à in ISO8859-1 or cp1252. If the code didn't change, only the DB upgrade, then it sounds like you changed from a not-UTF8 table encoding in 5.x to UTF8 in 8.x which probably also caused a lot of corruption when you moved the table data over.

set charset 'latin1';?  the encoding of your script file would only matter for literals in it
